# Elbow Method or/and Bayesian Information Criterion to select the optimal number of clusters

Tags: r, clustering, bic

I am working k-means cluster analysis. I am new in R and even newer with cluster analysis, but happy to learn.

I have managed to plot the following two figures to select the optimal number of clusters for my analysis. I thought that following the Elbow Method (EM) it can be 15 clusters, but using the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC), looks like it could be different. I am not using the: silhouette, Calinsky criterion, Affinity propagation, Gap Statistic, clustergrams, NbClust methods as they do not support the number of observations I got (at least not in R).

[image: EM - 15 clusters for k-means]

[image: BIC - I need help in analyzing this figure]

I would like some help to interpreter the BIC figure and if it somehow can support the EM to have 15 clusters. Many thanks.

Diego

Comment: The elbow method would suggest 3. After this, the curve shows the expected behavior for random data, roughly an exponential decrease. Maybe even just 1 cluster. Did you plot your data? How many clusters do you see?